# Is it normal to have a device on the home network broadcasting ARP all the IPs on the network?

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, wireshark, arp

I'm using Shark to scan my home network, and i noticed that a tablet is broadcasting, ARP protocol to all available IP on my network. Would this be a malicious attack from an app that i installed?

Answer (score 2):

The ARP request does level 2 broadcast by definition (otherwise, how should it work?). The ARP replies can be broadcast (for unsolicted announcements) or unicast (for solicited replies), but the latter are often snooped by many OS's anyway, so it could be as well a broadcast.

So, everything working as intended.

If you see ARP **spoofing** (some device trying to impersonate another device by answering to ARP requests that are not for the other device's IP address, or by sending unsolicited ARP replies with an IP address that is not its own), that's indeed malicious behavior; in that case, edit the question with the details (including which devices should have which IP address) so we can have a look at it.

But you can't find this out by the fact that it's broadcasting ARP messages, you'll have to look at the IP addresses.